# On the Definition of Gateaux Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, functional-calculus, gateaux-derivative

My question is about two different definitions Gateaux derivative. I have seen the following two definitions but whether they are equivalent or which one is better to use I am not sure about:

**Definition 1:** Derivative at $f$ with increment $h$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{ \theta \to 0} \frac{F[f+\theta h]- F[f]}{\theta}
\end{align*}

**Definition 2:** Derivative at $f$ with increment $h$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{ \theta \to 0} \frac{F[(1-\theta)f+\theta h]- F[f]}{\theta}
\end{align*}

Are these the same? Is there an advantage of using Def 1 vs Def 2?

Def.1 is how I been thought the Gateaux derivative  over vector space.

Def.2 I seen in the context of probability theory where derivative is taken over all probability distributions. The paper I read is also calling it Gateaux derivative.

I feel that the second one use if we want to take derivative over convex sets only. That is why we use $(1-\theta)f+\theta h$. But not sure completely?

Another question is if stationary point with one definition is also a stationary point with another?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you replace $h$ by $h - f$ in the first definition, you arrive at the second. Hence, they define different things. The typical definition is the first one.

Comment: Thank you. Do you possibly know what is the second definition called? I saw it in a paper they referred to it as weak derivative. But didn't give any reference to the origin.

Comment: Derivative with increment $h-f$ ;)

Comment: @gerw Have you hear of weak derivative?

Comment: Yes, I know weak derivatives.

Comment: @gerw Is that what the second definition is?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

The [Gâteaux derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) has a standard definition, which is your definition 1. It may be the case that some author in a particular situation is envisaging the limit in your definition 2, which is certainly not far away from the "official" Gâteaux derivative. But there is an essential difference: The "official" derivative is linear in the variable $h$, while the expression in definition 2 is not.

We see the same discrepancy when considering Taylor expansions in ordinary calculus. The $n$-jet, i.e., the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial, of a function $f$ at some point $a$ can be written as a polynomial in the "primary" variable $x$ as
$$j_a^{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(k)}(a)\over k!}(x-a)^k\ ,$$
but equivalently as a polynomial in the increment variable $X:=x-a$:
$$j_a^{n}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(k)}(a)\over k!}X^k\ .$$
The second view, which correspnds to your definition 1, seems much more natural.

Comment: Dear Chirstian thank you very much for your answer. Do you think that results in optimization like Lagrange or KKT conditions are the same for def 1 and def 2? Or today have to be some how modified for def 2?

Comment: I'd not dare to use definition 2 without really thinking about its meaning beforehand.

Comment: So, I am trying to use Gateaux derivative over space of probability distributions. I was researching the literature and they never use Def.1 but instead use Def. 2. However, I was not able to find why or the original source that say why its ok to use Def.2 instead of Def. 1.